# Two regex matches with space between the matches

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match a string with this regex:

The regex:

```
[ ](\d{4}|\d{4}[A-Za-z]{3})[ ]
```

NOTE: there might be 3 characters after the numbers, that's why [A-Za-z]{3} is in there.

This is the string I wan't to match in:

```
281320Z 26015KT 9999 3333 FEW028 SCT033 BKN053 16/10 Q1007=
```

So in this case it will only select 9999
since there's a space that match1 will reserve.
In this case:

```
281320Z 26015KT 9999 3333 4444 FEW028 SCT033 BKN053 16/10 Q1007=
```

9999 and 4444 will be selected.

How can i do so 9999, 3333, 4444 get selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
\b(\d{4})(?:\b|[A-Z]{3})
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJDci3/3)**

Comment: `There might be 3 characters after the numbers`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just a note: this regex is based on `\b` word boundaries. If you need to match only at start/end of string and between spaces, you'd need custom boundaries.

Comment: @Denniz glad to help

Answer (score 1):

`\b(\d{4})(?:[A-Za-z]{3})?\b` should do the trick.

`(?:)` is a non-capturing group, we use it with `?` to indicate that its content could appear zero or one time.

Retrieve the four digits by using `$1`